# Linux DATE have a few seconds gap between Two Servers?

Tags: linux, date, ntp

Let's say I have two different Servers located in same DataCenter. But when I check the `date` on both, there are a few second difference between them.

Example:

```
[root@server1 ~] # date
Tue Feb 23 11:40:22 SGT 2016

[root@server2 ~] # date
Tue Feb 23 11:40:10 SGT 2016
```

- Why is that so?
- And how to fix this (to be exactly the same) please?

---

**Note**:

I didn't setup `ntp` or anything (yet). I only just did this, whenever i got new Servers in hand:

```
# rm /etc/localtime
# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime
```

Comment: after you setup the ntp server?

Comment: Hi @DynoFu , no i didn't. I've edited the answer with more info. Can you please check pls? :)

Comment: without time synchronization, it's normal to have time drift, right? what is the ask here?

Comment: I simply asked: `Why is that so?` and `And how to fix this (to be exactly the same) please?` (Because i don't know. And i need help for this)

Comment: servers without synchronization will have time drift, i.e. each server runs in its own universe and have different time, and even they are configured to start in the same time, the clock might run at slightly different pace and cause time drift. fix it with synchronization, like ntp http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/

Comment: btw: the down vote is not from me...

Comment: Thanks. I now just came to understand i need to install "ntp" package. And configure to SG servers.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, as it has nothing to do with programming or programmers tools. This is a server related issue. It is probably better suited for one of the *nix sites ([ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]) or [sf] instead. (Not downvoting, although I did vote to close as off-topic.)

Comment: @DynoFu So, if you can, please put a simple wording (to install "ntp") as in answer. So that i can mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it with synchronization, install ntp:

http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/

Comment: Thanks for the help.